# Use fetch with Identity Server 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, identityserver4, fetch-api, isomorphic-fetch-api

How to use fetch with IdentityServer4 to get a JWT token, when using the resource owner password flow ? (which is not recommended most of the time).

Even if I should use the implicit flow, I want to use this flow because it's more convenienent in my situation for my spa application.
First, you'll find usefull information here to implement your solution :

- http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/2_resource_owner_passwords.html#requesting-a-token-using-the-password-grant
- https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/password-grant

But how to use [fetch-api] to get a token from IdentityServer 4 ?

```
    const form = new FormData();
    form.append('grant_type', 'password');
    form.append('username', username);
    form.append('password', password);
    if (this._settings.scope) {
        form.append('scope', this._settings.scope);
    }
    form.append('client_id', this._settings.clientId);
    if (this._settings.clientSecret) {
        form.append('client_secret', this._settings.clientSecret);
    }

    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        rejectUnauthorized: false, // when use local unverified certificate
        body: form
    };
```

I should receive a JWT token in response but I receive an http 500 Error. "Internal Server Error"

If I trace HTTP headers with fiddler, I got the following result :

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8888/ HTTP/1.1
content-type: multipart/form-data
accept-encoding: gzip,deflate
user-agent: node-fetch/1.0 (+https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch)
connection: close
accept: */*
content-length: 896
Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
```

Comment: what does the identityserver log say?

Comment: `dbug: IdentityServer4.Validation.PostBodySecretParser[0]
      Start parsing for secret in post body 
     crit: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Unhandled exception: System.IO.InvalidDataException: **Missing 
    content-type boundary.**
         at 
  
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.GetBoundary(MediaTypeHeaderValue contentType, Int32 lengthLimit)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.
    <InnerReadFormAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- `

Comment: When I remove "content-type" from my header, then it works !

I'll give an answer later, but also Note this code comes from a copy/paste that works with the request js module. (request overwrite the passed content-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my previous comment: If you want to use [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) in order to POST an authorized request with form data, you must not specify the content-type into the header. Since `fetch` will automatically populate it with the correct value ("multipart/form-data") and add the dynamically generated content-boundary.
Also note that you can use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams), if you prefer use the application/x-www-form-urlencoded content-type method.